# Unexpected behavior with button visibility - Android

Tags: android, android-button

im having problems with a simple task.

I have 2 Buttons and i want only one to be visible at same time, so when you touch one it hides and the other appears.

This is my code:

```
fromAnex = new Button(this);
    fromAnex.setText("from");
    fromAnex.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("ONClickListener", "from anex");
            returnFromAnex();
        }
    });
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,plano.getId());
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    rl.addView(fromAnex,params);
    fromAnex.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    toAnex = new Button(this);
    toAnex.setText("to");
    toAnex.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("ONClickListener", "Show anex");
            showAnex();
        }
    });
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,plano.getId());
    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    rl.addView(toAnex,params2);

private void showAnex()
{
    fromAnex.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    toAnex.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    private void returnFromAnex()
{
    fromAnex.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    toAnex.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I really cant understand why but that first call to `fromAnex.setVisibility(View.GONE);` is working as expected, the first call to showAnex() at `fromAnex.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
is working too but `toAnex.setVisibility(View.GONE);` right under doesnt work.

And after that nothing happens with buttons visibility when i touch.

Someone can see whats wrong with my code?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks.

**EDIT:**

That two methods arent complete, the rest are not related with this buttons visibility problem.

When i set visibility to gone just after creating the button it works but then i cant set visibility to gone again, thats the problem.

Comment: Is there some source code missing? There are no closing brackets `}` on your methods `showAnex` and `returnFromAnex`

Comment: Just to let you know, there is a view called `ViewSwitcher` which switches between two views and would fit in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your snippet I tried run the following and it works perfectly.I guess you are making some small mistake some where as DevTest said.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button fromAnex,toAnex;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relPra=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        rl.setLayoutParams(relPra);

        fromAnex = new Button(this);
        fromAnex.setText("from");
        fromAnex.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("ONClickListener", "from anex");
                returnFromAnex();
            }
        });
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        rl.addView(fromAnex,params);
        fromAnex.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fromAnex.setId(1);


        toAnex = new Button(this);
        toAnex.setId(2);
        toAnex.setText("to");
        toAnex.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("ONClickListener", "Show anex");
                showAnex();
            }
        });
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,fromAnex.getId());
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        rl.addView(toAnex,params2);

        setContentView(rl);
    }
    private void showAnex()
    {
        fromAnex.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toAnex.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
        private void returnFromAnex()
    {
        fromAnex.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toAnex.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```